# How can I import a SQL table that has ~350 columns?

Tags: mysql, import, varchar, tinytext

I am trying to import a SQL table on a Digital Ocean LAMP stack in phpMyAdmin and I am getting this error:

`#1118 - Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.`

I only have a single table but it has **~350 columns**. I am using `TINYTEXT` for most columns, thinking that will use less memory than `VARCHAR`.

When I remove ~100 columns, the import works.

Is there a limit to the number of columns I can import?

Or can a table only have so many `TINYTEXT` and `VARCHAR` columns?

Why is this error being thrown and how can I fix it? Is there a mySQL setting I can set or update in the mySQL config file? It's a VPS and I do have root access, so I can update something if need be.

Here is my table:

`` CREATE TABLE `rets_properties` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `acres` TINYTEXT,
  `addr` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `addl_mo_Fee` int(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `all_inc` TINYTEXT,
  `area` TINYTEXT,
  `a_c` TINYTEXT,
  `yr_built` TINYTEXT,
  `sqft` TINYTEXT,
  `apt_num` TINYTEXT,
  `area_code` TINYTEXT,
  `tv` int(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ass_year` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bsmt1_out` TINYTEXT,
  `bsmt2_out` TINYTEXT,
  `br` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `br_plus` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cable` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `cac_inc` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `central_vac` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `cert_lvl` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `comel_inc` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `community` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `community_code` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `dom` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cross_st` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `disp_addr` TINYTEXT,
  `drive` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `elevator` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `energy_cert` TINYTEXT,
  `constr1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `constr2_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `extras` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `den_fr` TINYTEXT,
  `farm_agri` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `fpl_num` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `oh_date1` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `oh_from1` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `oh_to1` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `comp_pts` TINYTEXT,
  `furnished` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `gar_spaces` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gar_type` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `green_pis` TINYTEXT,
  `heat_inc` TINYTEXT,
  `fuel` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `heating` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `hydro_inc` TINYTEXT,
  `num_kit` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kit_plus` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `laundry` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `laundry_lev` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `lease_term` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `legal_desc` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `level1` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `level10` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `level11` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `level12` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `level2` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `level3` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `level4` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `level5` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `level6` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `level7` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `level8` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `level9` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rltr` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `lp_dol` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `depth` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `front_ft` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `irreg` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `lotsz_code` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `mmap_page` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mmap_col` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mmap_row` TINYTEXT,
  `ml_num` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `municipality` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `municipality_district` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `municipality_code` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `oh_dt_stamp` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `orig_dol` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oth_struc1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `oth_struc2_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `outof_area` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `park_chgs` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prkg_inc` TINYTEXT,
  `park_spcs` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pay_freq` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `handi_equipped` TINYTEXT,
  `parcel_id` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `pix_updt` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `pool` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `occ` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `pvt_ent` TINYTEXT,
  `prop_feat1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `prop_feat2_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `prop_feat3_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `prop_feat4_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `prop_feat5_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `prop_feat6_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `county` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `ad_text` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `retirement` TINYTEXT,
  `rm1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm1_dc1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm1_dc2_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm1_dc3_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm1_len` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm1_wth` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm10_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm10_dc1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm10_dc2_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm10_dc3_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm10_len` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm10_wth` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm11_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm11_dc1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm11_dc2_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm11_dc3_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm11_len` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm11_wth` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm12_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm12_dc1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm12_dc2_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm12_dc3_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm12_len` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm12_wth` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm2_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm2_dc1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm2_dc2_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm2_dc3_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm2_len` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm2_wth` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm3_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm3_dc1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm3_dc2_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm3_dc3_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm3_len` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm3_wth` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm4_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm4_dc1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm4_dc2_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm4_dc3_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm4_len` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm4_wth` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm5_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm5_dc1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm5_dc2_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm5_dc3_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm5_len` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm5_wth` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm6_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm6_dc1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm6_dc2_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm6_dc3_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm6_len` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm6_wth` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm7_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm7_dc1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm7_dc2_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm7_dc3_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm7_len` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm7_wth` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm8_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm8_dc1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm8_dc2_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm8_dc3_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm8_len` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm8_wth` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm9_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm9_dc1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm9_dc2_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm9_dc3_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm9_len` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm9_wth` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rm_srch` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rms` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rooms_plus` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s_r` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `oh_date2` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `oh_from2` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `oh_to2` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `vend_pis` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `sewer` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `spec_des1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `spec_des2_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `spec_des3_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `spec_des4_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `spec_des5_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `spec_des6_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `st_num` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `st_sfx` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `st_dir` TINYTEXT,
  `st` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `style` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `yr` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `taxes` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oh_date3` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `oh_from3` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `oh_to3` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_own_srch` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_own1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `uffi` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp_sql` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `util_cable` TINYTEXT,
  `gas` TINYTEXT,
  `elec` TINYTEXT,
  `util_tel` TINYTEXT,
  `vtour_updt` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `tour_url` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `bath_tot` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wcloset_t1` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wcloset_p1` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wcloset_t1lvl` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `wcloset_t2` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wcloset_p2` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wcloset_t2lvl` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `wcloset_t3` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wcloset_p3` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wcloset_t3lvl` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `wcloset_t4` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wcloset_p4` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wcloset_t4lvl` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `wcloset_t5` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wcloset_p5` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wcloset_t5lvl` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `water` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `water_inc` TINYTEXT,
  `wtr_suptyp` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `waterfront` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `zoning` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `lse_terms` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `Idx_dt` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `lng` decimal(65,7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` decimal(65,7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_images` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `neighbourhood` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `share_perc` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `patio_ter` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `bldg_amen1_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `bldg_amen2_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `bldg_amen3_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `bldg_amen4_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `bldg_amen5_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `bldg_amen6_out` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `insur_bldg` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `corp_num` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `condo_corp` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `cond_txinc` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `ens_lndry` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `condo_exp` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `gar` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `stories` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `locker` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `locker_num` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `maint` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `park_lgl_desc1` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `park_lgl_desc2` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `park_spc1` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `park_spc2` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `park_desig` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `park_desig_2` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `park_fac` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `pets` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `prop_mgmt` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit_num` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `treb_class` TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `amps` TINYTEXT,
  `area_infl1_out` TINYTEXT,
  `area_infl2_out` TINYTEXT,
  `perc_bldg` TINYTEXT,
  `bay_size2` TINYTEXT,
  `bay_size2_in` TINYTEXT,
  `bay_size1` TINYTEXT,
  `bay_size1_in` TINYTEXT,
  `dba` TINYTEXT,
  `prop_type` TINYTEXT,
  `chattels` TINYTEXT,
  `ceil_ht` TINYTEXT,
  `ceil_ht_in` TINYTEXT,
  `com_cn_fee` TINYTEXT,
  `com_chgs` TINYTEXT,
  `crane` TINYTEXT,
  `days_open` TINYTEXT,
  `trlr_pk_spt` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrsdmnu` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrsdmhtft` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrsdmhtin` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrsdmwdft` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrsdmwdin` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrsdlnu` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrsdlhtft` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrsdlhtin` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrsdlwdft` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrsdlwdin` TINYTEXT,
  `employees` TINYTEXT,
  `inventory` TINYTEXT,
  `exp_actest` TINYTEXT,
  `fin_stmnt` TINYTEXT,
  `franchise` TINYTEXT,
  `freestandg` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrsglnu` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrsglhtft` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrsglhtin` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrsglwdft` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrsglwdin` TINYTEXT,
  `gross_inc` TINYTEXT,
  `heat_exp` TINYTEXT,
  `hours_open` TINYTEXT,
  `hydro_exp` TINYTEXT,
  `ind_area` TINYTEXT,
  `ind_areacd` TINYTEXT,
  `insur` TINYTEXT,
  `lp_code` TINYTEXT,
  `llbo` TINYTEXT,
  `lot_code` TINYTEXT,
  `mgmt` TINYTEXT,
  `terms` TINYTEXT,
  `minrenttrm` TINYTEXT,
  `net_inc` TINYTEXT,
  `oa_area` TINYTEXT,
  `off_areacd` TINYTEXT,
  `oper_exp` TINYTEXT,
  `orig_lp_code` TINYTEXT,
  `other` TINYTEXT,
  `out_storg` TINYTEXT,
  `perc_rent` TINYTEXT,
  `rail` TINYTEXT,
  `retail_a` TINYTEXT,
  `retail_ac` TINYTEXT,
  `seats` TINYTEXT,
  `soil_test` TINYTEXT,
  `sprinklers` TINYTEXT,
  `survey` TINYTEXT,
  `taxes_exp` TINYTEXT,
  `tot_area` TINYTEXT,
  `tot_areacd` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrstlnu` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrstlhtft` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrstlhtin` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrstlwdft` TINYTEXT,
  `shpdrstlwdin` TINYTEXT,
  `type_taxes` TINYTEXT,
  `bus_type` TINYTEXT,
  `utilities` TINYTEXT,
  `vac_perc` TINYTEXT,
  `volts` TINYTEXT,
  `water_exp` TINYTEXT,
  `yr_exp` TINYTEXT,
  `occupancy` TINYTEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8; ``

Comment: stop everything and read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @e4c5 There aren't really any relationships. Each row is a real estate property and each property has 163 attributes. I could split up the attributes into categories in separate tables but that would requiring significantly modifying my app, which I can't afford.

Comment: I would still say you have got the structure wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With 163 colums I recommend to think about a new structure. But for the moment ROWFORMAT=COMPRESSED could help.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
```

Or as you're talking about the config file: You could switch to InnoDB Barracuda instead.

In my.cnf:

```
innodb_file_per_table    
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
```

Comment: I actually saw this in another thread and tried this. I updated the `innodb_file_per_table` and `innodb_file_format` in `my.cnf` but that didn't work. Are you suggesting altering the original table or the new one I am trying to import into? Should I create the new table, alter it and then import it?

Comment: You can try to add ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED to your CREATE statement.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update `innodb_file_per_table=1` and `innodb_file_format=Barracuda` in your MySQL config.
2. But changing the config file doesn't take effect on your currently running instance, so you either have to restart mysqld, or else change the variables in the running instance:

   ```
   SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=1;
   SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
   ```
3. Rebuild the table now that you can use Barracuda.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE MyTableWith163Columns ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
   ```
4. Confirm that the change took effect:

   ```
   SHOW CREATE TABLE MyTableWith163Columns;
   ```

The DYNAMIC row format is probably sufficient to allow you to insert your data. COMPRESSED is not necessary. Both DYNAMIC and COMPRESSED row formats change the way blog/text columns are stored when the row gets too large, and basically allows for more columns per row.

For details read https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/

Comment: Thanks Bill. I tried updating the config with these settings but no luck. I also realized I actually have ~350 columns (a different table has 163). Locally using MAMP I can import the file in about 10 seconds and I don't get the error. It seems no matter what I do, I always hit 8Kib and get this error. I've updated my question with my `CREATE` statement for reference.